# Best practices to bundle Polymer components

Tags: polymer

Polymer dist/ folder has a single html file https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/tree/master/dist with a HTML import and a script tag. Most of the polymer elements doesn't even have a dist folder. Wouldn't it be a good practice to provide a single distribution bundle file like polymer.js and do the same for each polymer element available there?

There are some obvious advantages with this approach:

```
1. Minimum http requests to get the polymer core or a polymer element. 
2. Easy to use for the clients, just include the required element.
```

Example: Elements that depend on other shared elements,

```
- shared-element: /webcomponents/font-roboto/roboto.js
- custom-element1: uses shared-element
- custom-element2: uses shared-element
```

An app using custom-element1 and custom-element2 downloads /webcomponents/font-roboto/roboto.js
only once with a single http request.

```
<script src="../webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<script src="../webcomponents/custom-element1/custom-element1.js"></script>
<script src="../webcomponents/custom-element2/custom-element2.js"></script>
```

PS: the above custom-element1.js does the same thing as custom-element1.html expect that it is convenient to programmatically load and access the component.

I would like to hear from polymer team or other polymer developers/users on the best practices they are following to solve this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You only have to import the html file. Also, html imports get deduped and processed once. So if you include roboto (`<link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">`) in both your app as several custom-elements, it will be loaded only once (you can check it in the network panel)

Comment: @arbitter That's good to know about the dedup and one time loading. A follow up question on why Polymer elements are not distributing just the required component code in a dist/ folder?

Comment: +1 @jdepypere haven't verified yet but it looks like there's at least one HTTP request per component. Obviously that's bad for a real-world app that have dozens of components

Comment: @UAvalos you are absolutely correct, and Vulcanize is certainly the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you want is Vulcanize.
As of the time of this writing, for polymer 1.0, the instructions are:

> If you have an input HTML file, elements.html, that uses a number of HTML imports, you can run it through Vulcanize as follows:
>
> vulcanize elements.html -o elements.vulcanized.html
>
> The -o or --output flag will direct the output to a new file called elements.vulcanized.html. If you omit the -o flag, Vulcanize will print the output to stdout, which can be useful if you want to pipe it to another command.
>
> elements.vulcanized.html now contains a version of elements.html with all imports inlined and dependencies flattened. Paths to any URLs are automatically adjusted for the new output location, with the exception of those set in JavaScript.
>
> You can pass additional options to Vulcanize in the form of flags. For a full list of supported flags, see the official Vulcanize documentation.
>
> Here’s the same example from above. The extra flags tell Vulcanize to strip out comments, and to merge external scripts and CSS files into the vulcanized file.
>
> vulcanize -o elements.vulcanized.html elements.html --strip-comments --inline-scripts --inline-css

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/tools/optimize-for-production.html